# Is INC statement storing the result?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am new to assembly programming and I just cant understand this , when increment statement is applied to a register (for example INC BL) , does his value change ? I mean the increment statement stores the result right ? I am asking this because , I saw that CMP statement doesn't store the result .
Thanks for your time and appreciate your help !

Comment: Yes it does. Consult an instruction set reference for operation details.

Comment: @Jester thank you sir !

Comment: BTW, CMP stores result of comparison in flags

Comment: for learning asm on any processor you need to have the documentation handy, cant really get through it without a good reference manual...

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html for an HTML extract of Intel's SDM volume 2 ISA manual.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to other docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of the `INC` statement:

Adds 1 to the destination operand, while preserving the state of the CF flag. The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. This instruction allows a loop counter to be updated without disturbing the `CF` flag. (Use a ADD instruction with an immediate operand of 1 to perform an increment operation that does updates the `CF` flag.) This instruction can be used with a `LOCK` prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically.